# Will upgrading my laptop's wireless card make it support 802.11n?

Tags: wireless-networking, ubuntu-10.04, toshiba-laptop, 802.11n

I have a Toshiba Satellite P205-S7402 laptop, and it [supports](http://reviews.cnet.com/laptops/toshiba-satellite-p205-s7402/4507-3121_7-33428094.html?tag=mncol;subnav) 802.11b and g at present. I want to use 802.11n as well - can I just swap out the wireless card with a new PCI card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it would upgrade to 802.11n. But with laptops it isn't very easy to switch a PCI card. You could use a USB wireless adapter or a different kind of pluggable solution (PCMCIA or what it is called these days).

Comment: There's always option to get a miniPCI or miniPCIe card with the adapter.

Comment: Most people don't want to open their laptops, the manufacturers don't like it and you will have to say goodbye to your warranty. So a pluggable solution in a usb port would be the easiest ;)

Comment: @Robert: In the United States, a manufacturer can't legally void your warranty for this, it's prohibited by the Magnuson-Moss Act.

Comment: Don't know if Sudipta Chatterjee lives in the US, doesn't sound like it.

Comment: @Robert His profile says he lives in California.

Comment: Yes sir, I do - one of the many Indians in the Bay area :) My laptop is out of warranty anyway, and I recently cleaned it inside out. Thanks for your inputs - I'll go wifi card hunting now! :)